# Compilation error when deploy ASP.NET web form on server

Tags: mysql, asp.net

I used Visual Studio 2017 to create ASP.NET Web Forms with reference: MySql.data.dll. It works well on my Laptop. I upload all files on my server, I get Compilation Error

```
Compiler Error Message: CS0246: The type or namespace name 'MySql' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Web Forms target Framework: 2.0. My server support ASP.NET version 2.0

I have done many ways that I can search. But nothing change.
The last, I tried change version MySql.Data.dll file, change version framework, use some free hosting to test, but same error

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the [MySql Connector/NET](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/6.10.html) on the web server.

Comment: I use Windows Server, it was installed MySql

Comment: You still need to install the connector

Answer (score -1):

To solve this problem download MySql.Data.dll from

https://www.cryptool.org/trac/CrypTool2/export/2020/trunk/AppReferences/x64/MySql.Data.dll

Then right click on your project name, click on add reference and select MySql.Data.dll file

Comment: Thank for help but I was tried this way before ask my question